# Remove rows in pandas dataframe if any of specific columns contains a specific value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following df:

[Data Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBhyy.png)

I have not been able to figure out how to delete a row if any of the columns containing the word "test" is less than 95. For example, I would have to delete the entire index row 1 because the column "heat.test" is 80 (the same for rows 0 and 3). In other words, if only one column meets this condition, the whole row must be deleted.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and modify your question. Give us more details. Don't provide image links. Post your code and data directly into the question and use `code formating` for it. Also provide us with code that produce your sample data. Please help us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're asking:

```
df[~(df.le(95) & df.columns.str.contains("test"))].dropna()
```

Example (`df`):

```
    pump.test  Speed  feed.test  water
0   100        1000   70         0.2
1   100        2000   100        0.3
2   100        3000   100        0.4
3   95         4000   100        0.5
```

Output of the operation above:

```
    pump.test  Speed  feed.test  water
1   100        2000   100        0.3
2   100        3000   100        0.4
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work. I don't know why if a write "test" it does not take the columns that include that words so it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was not clear. Did you mean that a row need to be delete if `pump.test < 95` or `feed.test < 95`?

In that case don't *delete* or *remove* just do it the other way around und do a *positive selection*. Select all rows where `feed.test` **and** `pump.test` is [equal or greater](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ge.html) then `95`.

```
df.loc[df['feed.test'].ge(95) & df['pump.test'].ge(95)]
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it should to be deleted if any value in any column (with the word test in its name) is <95.  Your solution works, but I have a lot of columns and add one by one is slow. The other solution were more efficient in that regard.